# Adobe AIR Android FileStream issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, animate-cc

I tried to test blow code on **Android** device but i couldn't see any data in text fields. This code works well on **AIR Desktop** but in **Android** no. Is it difference between AIR **FileStream** function on **Desktop** and **Android**? Whats best **cross platform** code to save files and read write?

*This code works on Adobe Animate CC Android **Emulator**.*

```
import flash.filesystem.*;

             var prefsFile:File; 
            [Bindable] var prefsXML:XML; 
             var stream:FileStream; 

             function appStart():void
            { 
                prefsFile = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
                prefsFile = prefsFile.resolvePath("preferences.xml"); 
                readXML();
            }


             function readXML():void 
            {
                stream = new FileStream();
                if (prefsFile.exists) {
                    stream.open(prefsFile, FileMode.READ);
                    processXMLData();
                }
                else
                {
                    saveData();
                }

            }


             function processXMLData():void 
            {
                prefsXML = XML(stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable));
                stream.close();
                trace(prefsXML.Data1);
                trace(prefsXML.Data2);
                trace(prefsXML.Data3);
                txt_D1.text = prefsXML.Data1;
                txt_D2.text = prefsXML.Data2;
                txt_D3.text = prefsXML.Data3;

            }


             function windowClosingHandler(event:Event):void 
            {
                saveData();
            }


             function saveData():void
            {
                createXMLData(); 
                writeXMLData();
            }


             function createXMLData():void 
            {
                prefsXML = <preferences/>;
                prefsXML.Data1 = 1;
                prefsXML.Data2 = 2;
                prefsXML.Data3 = 3;
            }


             function writeXMLData():void 
            {
                var outputString:String = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n';
                outputString += prefsXML.toXMLString();
                outputString = outputString.replace(/\n/g, File.lineEnding);
                stream = new FileStream();
                stream.open(prefsFile, FileMode.WRITE);
                stream.writeUTFBytes(outputString);
                stream.close();
            }

appStart();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the correct way, we use it for AIR app (Desktop, Android, iOS) to store user data on device/PC, `File.applicationStorageDirectory` as well. So your code is cross-platform, if it does not work on Android, you probably have some other issue, but your code looks fine.

To read/write data to `File.applicationStorageDirectory` you don't need any explicit permissions in app manifest as well.

Comment: I selected all permission in settings and compiled again. now it works.

Comment: @MohammadSamir you don't need **all permissions**. Some people are turned off by an app that needs to [unnecessarily] access everything (SD card, phone contacts, GPS, etc...why?), try allowing "`read/write to device storage`" if your file is not saved/loaded within `File.applicationStorageDirectory`...

Answer (score 0):

If your Android version is 6.0 or more recent, you need to request permissions such as files or camera at runtime.

Ensure you have AIR 24.0 , with compiler option -swf-version=35, and do something like:

var permissionCheck : File = new File( "test") );

```
                    permissionCheck.addEventListener(PermissionEvent.PERMISSION_STATUS , function permissionStatusHandler( e : PermissionEvent ) :void
                    {                        
                        permissionCheck.removeEventListener(PermissionEvent.PERMISSION_STATUS , permissionStatusHandler);
                        if(e.status == PermissionStatus.GRANTED)
                        {                            
                            //  save your file
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            showPermissionError();
                        }

                    });

                    try
                    {
                        permissionCheck.requestPermission();

                    }
                    catch(error : Error)
                    {

                    }
```

See the AIR release notes for more info such as handling the camera permission.

https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_24_air_24_release_notes.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: johnny2hats, could you add to your answer? What you gave does work, but it's for File, which does have a requestPermission() method. The original question was about FileStream, and that doesn't have requestPermission(). Under Android 6 how would you get permission to use FileStream?